# Json submiting same data until refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a problem with submiting my "form" with json. Its not form in traditional way, i will post a code now:

```js
$('#select').on('change', function() {
      document.getElementById("info").setAttribute("data-info", this.value);
    })
    $('#info').on('click', function() {
      var id = $(this).data('info');
      add(info);
    });
    function add(info) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        contentType: content_type,
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.overrideMimeType(content_type);},
data: {'action': 'info_add', 'info': info },
        url: sitepath + 'info/all',
        success: function() { update(); }
      });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="select">
          <option value="1">data1</option>
          <option value="2">data2</option>
          <option value="3">data3</option>
          <option value="4">data4</option>
        </select>
    <div id="info">Button</div>
```

So as you see, when select is changed it adds "data-info" attribute to div. And when div is pressed it send data-info to php script. And the problem is that it always send the same value. But after refresh it sends fine only once and than again the same value as first. Its hard to explain but here is example:lets say that i change select to "data2" and press on div. It sends "2". But then when i change it to "data3", and press on div, it still sends "2", not "3". There is no cache set or something. Sorry for bad english and thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why are you not just reading the value when the button is clicked? You are setting the data attribute value on "info" and reading it from a different element.... `var id = $(this).data('info');` is what was clicked, not the div...

Comment: sorry, my fault) actually its info))

Comment: I would like to add that since you are using `get`, the browser is entitled to cache, so your server won't see changes whenever your browser tries to be smart and improve your browsing experience.  You would be well to use `post` or `put` or add a cache buster to the `get` request.  Adding `nonce=Date.now()` to the query string will prevent that from going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery for setting if you are also going to be reading it with jQuery

Change

```
document.getElementById("info").setAttribute("data-info", this.value);
```

to

```
$"#info").data("info", this.value);
```

Still wondering why you are using data atrrbutes when you are not just reading the value on demand.

```
add($('#select').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using confusing code, you can achieve the same using:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
      <option value="1">data1</option>
      <option value="2">data2</option>
      <option value="3">data3</option>
      <option value="4">data4</option>
    </select>
<div id="info">Button</div>


<script>
    $('.product__cart, .stock-product__cart').on('click', function() {
        var info = $('#select').val();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        data: {'action': 'info_add', 'info': info },
        url: sitepath + 'info/all',
        success: function() { update(); }
      });

    });
   </script>
```